# macOS: Is /etc/fstab file deprecated? What is the recommended config file then?

Tags: mount, automount

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. When I look for `/etc/fstab` file, I found `/etc/fstab.hd` file (no `/etc/fstab` file was present), and the file content says `IGNORE THIS FILE`.

But when I google, there are many articles still talking about `/etc/fstab` such as this [link](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7942). So should I create and use `/etc/fstab` file? If it's not recommended, what is the recommended config file then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

afaik, `fstab` doesn't exist by default. You have to create one, first time.

From your linked instructions...

> 7) Edit (or create) an fstab file by typing the following and pressing enter:
>        `sudo vifs`

Will do precisely that, edit - or create - an fstab file.
Once you've got it set up, it ought to work as expected. I have mine set with ACLs so it will let me edit it without jumping through hoops every time. iirc, by default it's set to root/wheel.

`fstab.hd` seems to be a red herring, but no amount of Googling has turned up what it is or was used for :/

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. so does it mean /etc/fstab is safe to be used in macos? I am just afraid it's not a recommended way.

Comment: It's absolutely fine, once you've got it set up.

Comment: Curious... what do you think you need to use it for?

Comment: I use it so clones, boot camp & spare drives don't auto-mount at boot.

Comment: How do you specify a mount point containing spaces? I want to mount a separate drive to /Users/davec/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music and have failed with all three methods, soft quotes, hard quotes, and escapes.

Comment: @tgunr - that would be best asked as a separate question, link back to this one for context if needed.

Comment: Does mounting via `/etc/fstab` give a "proper" connection? By that I mean when I mount my SMB-formatted NAS shares via `Finder`, and then I run `mount` fm the terminal, I see this string in the listing: `._afpovertcp._tcp.local`. I'll guess this has something to do with AFP & I wonder if that means trouble ahead?

Comment: @Seamus - that would be best to ask as a separate question. I haven't used afp in a decade.

Comment: I'd probably do that except the primary question in this case has already been asked & answered: "How to get a reliable connection for a NAS". It's odd this issue seems to come & go. And frustrating because I never have such issues on my Linux/BSD boxes. I s'pose I could ask something like `mount NAS using /etc/fstab`... would **you** be able to answer that?

Comment: @Seamus No, I've never used a NAS.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway. I've got a couple of ideas now at least. I've tried adding shares to the `Login items`, but that doesn't stop disconnects, and the `Command+K` incantation (which works fine on my old NAS) also has started frequent disconnects. And so, I've decided to avoid wasting further time on *Apple-ized* solutions & try something that is more Unix-like.

Comment: Well, for starters, don't use AFP. Apple stopped using that as its primary sharing method a decade ago. Trying to do this from fstab would only automount once, at boot. The rest of the issue won't be fixed by that.