# How do I ensure that my Mac mini will *always* connect to my Synology NAS with the username and password saved in the Keychain?

Tags: high-sierra, keychain, smb, nas, macos

I have a Mac mini - Intel i5 Mid 2011 - running MacOS High Sierra - the latest version of the OS it will allow to run - with all suitable software updates.

I have a Mac admin user with a username and password.

I have set it to automatically log this user in. (see below for how)

I have a Synology DiskStation NAS - running DSM 7.0.1-42218 Update 3.

It has SMB File Sharing enabled, and one shared volume.

Both devices are connected via ethernet to my WiFi hub - an Apple AirPort Extreme.

The shared volume is protected by a username and password distinct from the Mac user username/password.

I have manually mounted the shared volume, entered the username and password, and saved it in the Mac user's keychain.

I have an application that accesses data on the mounted shared volume set to launch at startup. (see below for how)

Every time the Mac mini boots, it automatically logs in as the user and launches the application. (see below for how)

Most times - about nine out of ten times - when the application is launched, it connects to the shared volume and mounts it (with username and password).

Occasionally - about one time out of every ten, it attempts to mount the drive - and pops up a dialog asking for the username and password.

How can I prevent the Mac from forgetting the saved login in the keychain OR how can I prevent the Synology from rejecting the keychain-provided password (I don't know why this happens - how can I investigate further)?

It is not as consistent as definitely every tenth attempt.

And it is made worse by the fact that this Mac mini is running headless and so I don't even see the dialog until I find that my Application is not running, and so I investigate

**Update**

I am auto-logging in to the Mac through Settings --> Users & Groups --> Login Options --> Automatically Login.

And I am auto-logging in to the Shared Volume because I have saved the username & password in Keychain the first time I connected to it.

The app is being launched through Settings --> Users & Groups --> Login Items

Comment: I don't know how you're doing this auto-login, but is there no way to test it & retry if it failed?

Comment: @Seamus, I am auto-logging in to the Mac through Settings --> Users & Groups --> Login Options --> Automatically Login. And I am auto-logging in to the Shared Volume because I have saved the username & password in Keychain the first time I connected to it.

Comment: OK - I do the same thing on my Macbook-Synology, but it's always there when I need it. From your description, I gather this is automated: user login, app launch & authentication - no delay. As a first guess, maybe look into the timing? That's what I meant by testing it. Can you delay the app launch? Is this done in `launchd`?... a `launchctl` script?

Comment: @Seamus, the app is being launched through Settings --> Users & Groups --> Login Items.

Comment: Regarding timing, is there perhaps a way I could mount the shared volume on *system* startup before even the user is logged in. It is an SMB share?

Comment: That's what I'd try. I'm not aware of **any** Apple documentation on how to effect this using `launchd`, but @tetsujin posted a [solution for using `/etc/fstab`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332844/149366) that may work (I've not tried it myself).